# Can mobX tell me which elements in an observable array or object were changed?

Tags: mobx, mobx-react

I am using mobX with React and Three.js. The Three.js scene is rendered in a React component. I use the mobX store for information rendered both in normal React components as well as the 3D scene (this is not a graphics or React question though).

To update the ThreeJS scene when relevant changes happen in the mobX store, I have a custom reaction:

```
import { reaction } from 'mobx';
import { observer, inject } from 'mobx-react';
// ...

@inject('matchStore')
@observer
class MapViewport extends React.Component {

    // Update the scene when the map state changes
    reactToSceneUpdate = reaction(
        () => return this.props.matchStore.territories,
        () => this.updateScene()
    );

    // ...
```

That reaction is correctly updating the scene when `matchStore.territories` changes. matchStore. `matchStore.territories` is an array computed from an observable object:

```
class MatchStore {

    @observable territoriesById = {};

    @computed get territories() {
        return Object.values(this.territoriesById);
    }

    // ...
```

The problem is that `matchStore.territories` is a very large array, and the `updateScene` function has to iterate through every member of the array to check if it needs graphics updates. I've noticed that this takes some time and has a noticeable lag.

Is there a way that mobX lets me get the specific member(s) of the array that triggered the change?

Alternatively, can I use the observable object in the reaction (`matchStore.territoriesById`) and somehow get the member(s) of the object that were changed?

My best idea so far is to set a flag on the updated members that's checked in the updateScene loop (and members not in need of updating are instantly skipped over), but I was hoping for a more implicit solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get separate information about updates to individual array elements, define a `Territory` class with its own `@observable` properties, and create an instance of that class to be each element of the array. Set up a separate reaction for each element. That way, if its data changes you would make specific updates to the scene relating to that element.